# '☃'.encode("utf-8") is different from ord('☃')

Tags: python

I tested the following unicode:

```
In [34]: snowman = "\u2603"
In [35]: snowman
Out[35]: '☃'
```

encode snowman

```
In [36]: ds = snowman.encode("utf-8")
In [37]: ds
Out[37]: b'\xe2\x98\x83'
```

However, when I checked it with ord()

```
In [38]: ord('☃')
Out[38]: 9731
```

It's different with b'\xe2\x98\x83'

How could I understand it?

Comment: But why would you expect these to be the same? They do different things.

Comment: `hex(9731)` equals `'0x2603'`.

Comment: To echo @unutbu, hex 9731 == unicode 2603 == bytes \xe2\x98\x83

Comment: UTF-8 is designed so that 1) code points 0-127 are represented using single bytes, the same as in ASCII and 2) any multi-byte character is represented using bytes greater than 128. (This allows easy detection of non-ASCII characters and ensures that if you strip all chars > 128, you will not strip partial characters.) It's an *encoding* of Unicode but *it is not itself Unicode.* It's a mapping of Unicode to a stream of bytes. There will be differences. If you want an exact mapping of code points to bytes, try UTF-32.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) returns a Unicode codepoint ---
a somewhat arbitrary number that identifies the given character.

[`encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode)
returns a sequence of bytes that represents the given string in some encoding...
if the string *can* be represented in that encoding.

The encoding and the codepoint are only related in the sense that they both identify the same character.

An excellent introduction to the difference between *bytes* and *characters* is Ned Batchelder's
"[Pragmatic Unicode, or, How Do I Stop the Pain?](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html)"
(36 minute [video from PyCon US 2012](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgHbC6udIqc)).
He covers both Python 2 and 3, and the drastically different approaches they take to solving this problem.